# JSON stringify with variables in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, stringify

I'm trying to POST some JSON where I need to include some values from input fields. I have two input fields with the IDs of username and password.

```
data = JSON.stringify({
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "POST",
  "params": {
    "params": {"username": $('#username').val(), "password":  $('#password').val()}
  }
});
```

I can send it perfectly fine when I hardcode the values, the issue is that it doesn't send the values from the input fields. What am I doing wrong?

I'm sending it like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url:url,
  type:"POST",
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: "json",
  data : data,
  headers: {
    'content-type': "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  },
  success: function(data){
        $("#result").append('<p>Token: ' + data.result.token + '</p>');
        $("#result").append('<p>Name: ' + data.result.Customer.Name.value + '</p>');
        $("#result").append('<p>ID: ' + data.result.Customer.ID + '</p>');
  },
  error: function(data, status, xhr) {
alert("Error");
  }

});
```

I tried simplifying things, so I'm adding the value to a `div` on the click of a button. That works just fine:

```
$("#login").click(function() {
  $('#test').append($('#username').val());
});
```

**ANSWER:** As David mentioned in the comments, it's because I declared the data variable outside the function.

Comment: `"params": {
    "params": ... } } ` doesn't seem logical

Comment: If the code works fine when you hard code the values there is something wrong with the way you access your values. What does a `console.log(data)` look like? Do the fields exist? Is the declaration of `data` being evaluated at a point when there is a value in the fields?

Comment: Yup, if I just return the values to the screen, they work fine. I'm starting to think if stringify doesn't allow dynamic data?

Comment: `stringify` will yield a string representation of whatever object you pass to it, regardless of how that object was constructed. If you can pass the exact same object. So if hard coded values work then there is something wrong with the way you access your values.  What does a `console.log(data)` look like? Do the fields exist? Is the declaration of data being evaluated at a point when there is a value in the fields? What does _return the values to the screen_ mean?

Comment: Sorry, I mean just appending the values to an object on page load. `console.log(data)` shows the Object I'm requesting.

Comment: Will you please paste the result of `console.log(data)` into comments or your answer?

Comment: `var data = JSON.stringify(x)` will create a string representation of the object `x` as it is at the time when that line of code is evaluated. `data` will just be a string, nothing magical about it. If this is being done in page load, for instance, and your `<input id="username" />` is empty at the time of page load, then the value of that property in `x` will be an empty string, and the resulting `data` string will reflect that. If you enter a value in to the input field _at a later point_, that will not magically change the content of your `data` string variable.

Comment: Ah, that's the issue. I moved the declaration inside the click() function. That made it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
"params": {
 "params": {"username": $('#username').val(), "password":  $('#password').val()}
}
```

in

```
"params": {"username": $('#username').val(), "password":  $('#password').val()}
```

you are declaring params twice in a moment

Comment: I know, but that's the way I need to send it. It's actually declared that way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use dataType: "string"

Answer (score 0):

Added the answer in the original question. Especially thanks to David Hedlund that helped me in the right direction.